# Can I transform a folder into a php page?

Tags: php, url, directory

first of all, I want to apologize for my English level. I am currently looking **to turn a folder into a php file** (php page). This may seem hard to understand, but in reality it is very simple. Maybe is it just my formulation that is bad. Clearly this is what I want to do:

- I have a page name **manage.php** that serves as home to manage ads and allows a member to choose the ad he wants to manage.
- I have another page named **update.php** that allows the member to update his announcement.
- I would like my manage.php page to act as a folder so that my URL address of my update.php page is **www.example.com/manage/update.php**.

In other words, I would like my page update.php to become a sub-page (I can not find other terms/words in my head?) of the page manage.php ! My question is, should I create unnecessarily  a folder named "manage" or can I link these two pages differently?

Comment: can you post the code for manage.php?

Comment: That would be pretty tricky to do. There are various methods. I know .htaccess with other slight modifications could work. Really though, why change what already exists? Or keep the manage.php file and create a manage/ directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about changing the name of manage.php?. Under manage folder, you should named your manage.php into index.php to make it the first page to find under manage folder.

www.example.com/manage/ will load the index.php

and put your update.php under manage folder and call it like this
www.example.com/manage/update.php will load the update.php.

I haven't tried but i guess it will work.

Comment: All the solutions here work, but this one is so simple and so easy, thanks a lot ! So many possibilities with this solution

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/manage/update.php$ update.php [L]
```

You can place an .htaccess file with that. Or either create an alias on your `httpd.conf` on the Apache server

Answer (score 1):

I think you're saying that you want to run both of your PHP files together, at the same time. idk, maybe I misunderstood, but here's how to do that.

1) Include the filename for the "inner" script (update.php) in the url by passing it in the query string (`?manage=update.php`) to the "outer" script (manage.php). For now, your URL will look like this:

```
http://www.example.com/manage.php?manage=update.php
```

2) In manage.php, wherever you want to include the inner script, just add this line:

```
include($_GET['manage']);
```

Now, you've got both scripts, with update.php acting like a "sub-page" to manage.php, like you said. But you're URL is all messed up. You can fix that with an `.htaccess` file.

3) Create a file called ".htaccess" and put it in the directory where manage.php is. update.php should be in that same directory as well. Copy the following into your `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^manage/([^/]*)$ /manage.php?manage=$1 [L]
```

Now your URL will look like this

```
http://www.example.com/manage/update.php
```

And if you ever want to make other sub-pages, just put them in the same directory and call in the same way with no changes needed.